# Adding tile size and compression type for ArcPy code?

Tags: arcpy, raster, copy, compression

I have to add tilesize and compression type to the following code

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CopyRaster_management("c:/data/background.tif",
                           "c:/fdgb/CpRaster.gdb/fgdbRD","DEFAULTS",
                           "0","9","","","8_BIT_UNSIGNED")
```

How do I add these two lines to above code?

```
arcpy.env.compression ="NONE 75"
arcpy.env.tileSize ="0.1 0.1"
```

Comment: You should review the documentation. Neither of your environment settings is correct (`NONE` doesn't support a *value*,  and `tileSize` is in *pixels*). The doc also has examples of how environment settings are used.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can just type it before copy raster:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.compression ="NONE" #beware, if NONE, then there is no value

arcpy.env.tileSize ="256 256" # has to be in pixels

arcpy.CopyRaster_management("c:/data/background.tif",
                           "c:/fdgb/CpRaster.gdb/fgdbRD","DEFAULTS",
                           "0","9","","","8_BIT_UNSIGNED")
```

compression value is only available for:

```
Compression quality (1-100)—When JPEG, JPEG_YCbCr, JPEG2000
compression is chosen, the compression quality also needs to be specified. 
The valid compression quality value ranges are from 1 to 100, with 75 being the default.
```

For the rest, use only:

```
arcpy.env.compression ="LZW"
```

update:

```
>>> arcpy.env.compression = 'NONE'
>>> arcpy.CopyRaster_management("nieder_00005.tif", r'C:\temp\tif.tif') 
<Result 'C:\\Temp\\tif.tif'>

>>> dsc = arcpy.Describe(tif.tif)
>>> dsc.compressionType
u'None'

>>> dsc_old = arcpy.Describe('nieder_00005.tif')
>>> dsc_old.compressionType
u'LZW'
```

Comment: Its not working, still the compression is in "LZW". it is not converted to "NONE"

Comment: I updated my answer, it is working. Just checked it with a random raster.

Comment: If you still can not get it to work. Set output to a file, not to a database. I am not sure, if there are any settings in gdb, that are overriding the environments